# Referencing \pgfmathsetmacro variable inside an \ifthenelse statement

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals

How do I correctly reference a value calculated using a \pgfmathsetmacro definition when defining the check condition of an \ifthenelse statement?

Example Problem; Randomly scattering nodes within a circle...

Using {1>0.5} as my \ifthenelse check condition, the following Tikz picture plot works as expected;

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{ifthen, tikz, pgfplots} \usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \foreach \i in {1,...,10}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{random()}  
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\theta}{random()*360}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\weight}{random()} 
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\r*sin(\theta)}    
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\r*cos(\theta)}
            \ifthenelse{1>0.5}{\node[circle, inner sep=1pt, fill=black] (\i) at (\x,\y) {};}{}
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But I have no such luck when considering the loop dependant \ifthenelse check condition {\weight>0.5} below;

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots} \usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \foreach \i in {1,...,10}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{random()}  
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\theta}{random()*360}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\weight}{random()} 
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\r*sin(\theta)}    
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\r*cos(\theta)}
            \ifthenelse{\value{\weight}>0.5}{\node[circle, inner sep=1pt, fill=black] (\i) at (\x,\y) {};}{}
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Is this a syntax error, or something more complicated? I can't for the life of me figure out why this won't compile properly...

Comment: You don't need `ifthen`, Use for example, `\pgfmathparse{(\weight>0.5)?1:0}\ifdim\pgfmathresult pt>0pt\node[circle, inner sep=1pt, fill=black] (\i) at (\x,\y) {};\fi`

Comment: Very nice work around, thanks! 

However, in order to avoid any future frustrations, do you know if there is in fact a "correct syntax" with which to solve the referencing problem above? Personally it doesn't seem like too complicated a problem to ask of the \ifthenelse branch function? Surely there must be some way of logically checking \pgfmathsetmacro values inside of it? Or has \pgfmathparse been specifically defined in order to control this type of behaviour? Just wondering...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since no further ideas seem to be readily forthcoming, I'll convert percusse's comment (above) into an accepted answer, and close this question...

> You don't need `ifthen`, Use for example, `\pgfmathparse{(\weight>0.5)?1:0}\ifdim\pgfmathresult pt>0pt\node[circle, inner sep=1pt, fill=black] (\i) at (\x,\y) {};\fi`

[All credit to percusse]