# PGF/Tikz Ifthenelse complaining about missing num

Tags: tikz-pgf, ifthenelse

This MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    overline/.style={black,fill},
    underline/.style={black,fill=white}]
    
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Px}{2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Py}{3}

    \foreach \Ax/\Ay in {2/1, 0/3, 2/.5, -2/-1, 1.5/-1.5} {    
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\AdotP}{ \Ax * \Px + \Ay * \Py }
        \ifthenelse{\AdotP > 0}
        {%
            \draw[overline] (\Ax, \Ay) circle [radius=2pt];
        }%
        {%
            \draw[underline] (\Ax, \Ay) circle [radius=2pt];
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

is failing with

> Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
>
> . l.447         \ifthenelse{\AdotP > 0}
> I was expecting to see `<',` =', or `>'. Didn't.  main.tex, line 447

And

> Missing number, treated as zero.
>
> . l.447         \ifthenelse{\AdotP > 0}
> A number should have been here; I inserted `0'. (If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number, look up` weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

How this can be fixed?

Comment: maybe check this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182635/referencing-pgfmathsetmacro-variable-inside-an-ifthenelse-statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\AdotP` is a decimal number, but `\ifthenelse` handles only integers. You could use `\lengthtest` as test (but using the functions offered by pgf is better):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    overline/.style={black,fill},
    underline/.style={black,fill=white}]

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Px}{2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Py}{3}

    \foreach \Ax/\Ay in {2/1, 0/3, 2/.5, -2/-1, 1.5/-1.5} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\AdotP}{ \Ax * \Px + \Ay * \Py }
        \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\AdotP pt > 0pt}}
        {%
            \draw[overline] (\Ax, \Ay) circle [radius=2pt];
        }%
        {%
            \draw[underline] (\Ax, \Ay) circle [radius=2pt];
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain about the PGF functions too?